# Virtuoso 42000 Error SQ070:SECURITY: Must have SELECT privileges on view DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2 for group ID 108 (SPARQL), user ID 108 (SPARQL)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to run the following query on Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor and I get this error:

```
Virtuoso 42000 Error SQ070:SECURITY: Must have SELECT privileges on view DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2 for group ID 108 (SPARQL), user ID 108 (SPARQL)
```

Query:

```
SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-unconnected-variables 1 define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?country ?pop
WHERE {
    VALUES ?country {
        dbr:Scotland
        dbr:England
        dbr:Wales
        dbr:Northern_Ireland
        dbr:Ireland
    }

    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        ?country dbp:populationCensus ?pop .
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me sort this out, I am very new to this field!

Comment: on which endpoint are you doing this? And why the SERVICE clause?

Comment: Note, public DBpedia endpoint won't allow for federated queries via `SERVICE` - and right now, I don't see why you would do this here in your query. So, why?

Comment: moreover, those `VALUES` won't be visible inside the `SERVICE` request. You have to put it inside the clause, otherwise it will just get all bindings matching the triple pattern, and afterwards doing a join.

Comment: Just a guess, but you want this: `SELECT ?country ?pop
WHERE {
    VALUES ?country {
        dbr:Scotland
        dbr:England
        dbr:Wales
        dbr:Northern_Ireland
        dbr:Ireland
    }

   ?country dbp:populationCensus ?pop .
}` running on http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: I am running the queries on dbpedia.org/sparql and my goal is to extract more data at a time using the VALUES clause.  I found a tutorial from which I extracted the previous code, but obviously I didn't know on which circumstances SERVICE clause works :(

Comment: If writing like this, I still get no results

Comment: `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?country ?pop
WHERE {
    VALUES ?country {
        dbr:Scotland
        dbr:England
        dbr:Wales
        dbr:Northern_Ireland
        dbr:Ireland
   }
    ?country dbp:populationCensus | dbo:populationTotal ?pop .
        
}`

Comment: And to be more clear, what I want to do is to get from just one query multiple data( in this example country + population) so as not to run a new query each and every time for every country separately.

Comment: I understand the purpose of `VALUES`, I was just saying that `SERVICE` wasn't necessary here. And ok, your property was wrong for the given countries. Note, it's likely to get multiple values for a single country with your query, i.e. check `dbr:Albania`. That's the bad news here, data isn't clean and people have to to data cleansing. You could also check for DBpedia Live (http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) which does contain the more recent facts from Wikipedia - the public DBpedia endpoint is still outdated and based on a dump from 2016. And you could also use Wikidata as a source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reported error resulted from attempting to run a Federated SPARQL (a/k/a SPARQL-FED) query — that is, a query using a `SERVICE` clause — on a public Virtuoso endpoint which is not set up to permit such queries.

As @AKSW noted, the `SERVICE` clause is unnecessary anyway, because the "remote" endpoint in your query is the same endpoint on which you're running the main query.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, using iSQL

```
grant SPARQL_LOAD_SERVICE_DATA to "SPARQL";
grant SPARQL_SPONGE to "SPARQL";
```

Documentation: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksDiscoverSPARQFedCapabilitiesSPARQL

and

https://github.com/dice-group/LargeRDFBench#running-sparql-11-queries

Comment: This answer is not relevant to this question, as this answer requires SQL access and DBA privileges on the SPARQL endpoint. Such access and privileges are not available to the general public on the DBpedia endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Virtuoso 07.20.3239. On that version the solution is to grant explicit permissions to the objects in question:

```
GRANT SELECT ON "DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2" TO "SPARQL";

GRANT EXECUTE ON "DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_IMP" TO "SPARQL";
```